# Typescript AST factory - how to use comments?

Tags: typescript, comments, factory, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following ast:

```
import { factory as f } from 'typescript'

const typeDeclaration = f.createTypeAliasDeclaration(
  [],
  [],
  'TestType',
  [],
  f.createTypeLiteralNode([
    f.createPropertySignature([], 'str', undefined, f.createKeywordTypeNode(SyntaxKind.StringKeyword)),
  ]),
)
```

Which represents:

```
type TestType = {
  str: string
}
```

How would I build an AST representing this code? Are comments even part of the AST?

```
/* Some comment on type */
type TestType = {
  /* Some comment on property */
  str: string
}
```

I have seen there are many methods available on the `factory` object for creating doc-comments, but I haven't found any examples on how to use them.

In case it's only possible in doc-comment format I'd be interested in examples for that too:

```
/** Some comment on type */
type TestType = {
  /** Some comment on property */
  str: string
}
```

Comment: Why do want non-doc comments in the AST? I'm pretty sure they get trimmed out since there have functional purpose, as opposed to doc comments that do serve intellisense and documentation.

Comment: @AlexWayne I'm generating code. I'd like to figure out if comments are part of the AST or not, and if yes how to use them, as the generated code should contain comments.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit perplexed on this then. Comments appear to be absent in the AST, and yet typescript can pass them through from TS to JS. So how can it do that if they aren't in the AST?

Comment: @AlexWayne also there seem to be intellisense, refactoring, etc on doc-comments in VSCode, which indicates to me that at least doc comments are part of the AST. Probably just tricky to use, hence the question :)

Comment: It appears that doc comments get attached to the node they are documenting. You can view the AST of any code in the typescript playground by click Setting and turning that feature on. So does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205260/how-do-i-add-jsdoc-comments-to-typescript-generated-with-the-typescript-ast-api answer your question? Toward the end of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17146 as also a method of creating JSDoc comments.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @AlexWayne's answer it seems you can wrap each `Node` into an `addSyntheticLeadingComment` call. You can then specify the raw text that goes between the `/*` and `*/` tokens.

```
const typeDeclWithComment = addSyntheticLeadingComment(
  typeDeclaration, // The node
  SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia, // Node type
  'my comment', // the comment text between comment tokens
  true, // add a trailing newline after */
)
```

Which will result in something like this:

```
/*my comment*/
type TestType = {
  str: string
}
```

In case you want to do doc-comment style comments, you can do something like:

```
const typeDeclWithComment = addSyntheticLeadingComment(
  typeDeclaration,
  SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia,
  '*\n * First line of doc-comment\n * second line of doc-comment\n ', 
  true, 
)
```

Which will be printed as:

```
/**
 * First line of doc-comment
 * second line of doc-comment
 */
type TestType = {
  str: string
}
```

But you are on your own with indentation.